# Let $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and $R = \{(a, c), (b, b), (c, a)\}$ be a relation on $A$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

> Let $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and $R = \{(a, c), (b, b), (c, a)\}$ be a relation on $A$.

Determine whether $R$ is reflexive, symmetric, transitive and anti-symmetric, or not.

Comment: All four are very straightforward; can you at least determine whether $R$ is reflexive?

Comment: Are you clear about what it means for $R$ to be reflexive, symmetric, transitive, and/or anti-symmetric?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $A = \{a, b, c\}$ and $R = \{(a, c), (b, b), (c, a)\}$ be a relation on $A$.

**Reflexive?** 
We need to have that *for all* $x \in A$, $(x, x) \in R$.

- Is this true for $a \in A?\quad$ So...

**Symmetric?** 
We need to have that *for all* $x, y \in A$, *if* $(x, y) \in A$ *then* $(y,x)\in A$.

- Hint: there is only one pair of values to be concerned about: $(a, c) \in R$. If $(c, a)\in R$, then the relation is symmetric.

**Transitive**? 
We need to have that *for all* $x, y, z \in A$, *if* $(x, y)$ and $(y, z)$ are in $R$, *then* $(x, z)$ is in $R$.

- Note that $(a, c), (c, a) \in R,$ but $(a, a) \notin R.\quad$  So...

**Antisymmetric?** 
We need to have that *for all* $x, y \in A$, *if* $(x, y), (y, x) \in R$, *then* $x = y$.

- We can see that $(a, c), (c, a) \in R$, but $a \neq c$. So $R$ is not antisymmetric, since it violates the definition of antisymmetry.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 
Really helpful .

Comment: My pleasure, thejimzee!

Comment: Yes i do know what it means. 
e.g. R is not reflexive if there is an element "a" in A such that (a,a)∉R. That is some element "a" of A is not related to itself. 

For Symmetric: R is not symmetric if there are elements a and b in A such that {a,b}∈R but (b,a)∉R

For Transitive:
R is not Transitive if there are elements a, b, c in A such that 
if(a,b) ∈R and (b,c)∈R but (a,c)∉R

please correct me if i am wrong .

Comment: You've got it! =)

Comment: once again thanks for your time.